# Error Installing MySQL in Parrot Linux

Tags: linux, software-installation, mysql, parrotsec

I recently installed Parrot KDE Security OS on VMWare.
I was having trouble using MariaDB like connecting MariaDB and NodeJs was very tiredsome work than connecting MySQL and NodeJs. And there was way too less resources for MariaDB than MySQL.

So I uninstalled MariaDB completely from the Parrot.

But now when I am trying to install MySQL I am facing too many issues. I have scorched the stacks, githubs and finally asking here.

The below is the command I came across various times and I used this.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

But I am getting the following Error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
```

Please can you give me complete instructions for installing MySQL.

And I literally searched for everything for this issue. I went through MySQL site and everywhere. I also went through [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/). Your help will be much appreciated. Thank You so much.

Comment: Try `sudo apt clean all; sudo apt update; sudo apt install mysql-server` . If you still get the same error, then this package is probably not available in the official repos for Parrot Linux. What is wrong with using mariadb? What exactly is tiresome in mariadb?

Comment: @GMaster I tried those commands. But it still gives an error `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate`

Comment: @GMaster I dont know much about MariaDB and I was having another issue connecting MariaDB with NodeJS. It also took a much of my time.

Comment: You will need to download and install MySQL from their official website: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ but I think you will run into more issues with the installation itself. If I were you I would install mariadb and try to sort out the issues. Most of what applies to mysql also applies to mariadb. (After Oracle took over MySQL the original developers of MySQL left and forked MySQL to create mariadb.)

Comment: @GMaster Yes I will install mariaDB now. But will continue to look for solution of this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

Then...

```
systemctl start mysql  
systemctl status  mysql
```

Now
You're good to go.

Comment: This installs mariadb, though, not the mysql that the OP wanted

Answer (score -1):

The solution.

1. apt install mariadb
2. service mysql start

All good.

Comment: This installs mariadb, though, not the mysql that the OP wanted